# Horizontally scrolling navbar not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was recently linked to a post explaining how to add a navbar that scrolls to the right or left to reveal more tabs. The complete JSFiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/k63t7tqo/3/

Apparently I need to put some code here, so here's the HTML from the fiddle:

```js
$('.direction-right').click(function() {
    var margin = $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top');
    console.log(margin);
    console.log('-' + ($('.navbar-nav').height() - 50) + 'px');
    $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top', margin == '-' + ($('.navbar-nav').height() - 50) + 'px' ? margin : '-=50px');
});

$('.direction-left').click(function() {
    var margin = $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top');
    $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top', margin == '0px' ? '0px' : '+=50px');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top', 0);  
    }
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .direction-right, .direction-left {
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 51px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: calc(100% - 52px);
    }
    
    .direction-right, .direction-left {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">     
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
          
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <a href="#" class="direction-left pull-left navbar-brand"><</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="1.html">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="2.html">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="3.html">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="4.html">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="5.html">Menu 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="6.html">Menu 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="7.html">Menu 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="8.html">Menu 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="9.html">Menu 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="10.html">Menu 10</a></li>
            <li><a href="11.html">Menu 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="12.html">Menu 12</a></li>
          </ul>
            <a href="#" class="direction-right pull-left navbar-brand">></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem I am having is that:

A) When I click the right and left arrows, the navbar itself moves UP and DOWN the page, even overlapping other words/content.

B) The navbar does not match the basic blue Bootstrap theme I have going on.

Problem B I can most likely figure out myself, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the navbar is moving up and down instead of scrolling to the right and left in-place. Thanks in advance for any assistance. This website is great, and you people are awesome.

Edit: I guess it's worth noting that I am using Bootstrap with DataTables and LESS, not just a basic page.

Comment: Please include your CSS and JS in your post as well. Fiddles can fade away which would render your question useless to future users.

Comment: Went ahead and added your code from the Fiddle to a snippet here on the site. Adds all your code for you, and provides a working, well, snippet, of your code that will stick around with your question. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Thank you for the edit. :)

Comment: Using the JS.Fiddle example you provided I added a large container to the page and made it use bootstrap and the example appears to be working correctly minus a few styling things that could be corrected. I would compare your code to this to see whats going on. [JS.Fiddle Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/k63t7tqo/11/)

Comment: Hmm @crazymatt I'm not really sure what the issue is. I have a container in my page as well, and a DataTable, but for some reason the arrow makes the nav bar simply move UP the page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The reason its jumping back to the top of the page is because you are using a JQuery click event and the hashtag `#` is an anchor tag that's telling the browser to scroll back to the top of the page when its clicked. I think the easiest way to fix this is to change the right and left arrows to `span` tags that way the anchor link wont be called and your page wont jump around when a user navigates your page.

```
    <span class="direction-left pull-left navbar-brand"><</span>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="1.html">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="2.html">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="3.html">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="4.html">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="5.html">Menu 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="6.html">Menu 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="7.html">Menu 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="8.html">Menu 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="9.html">Menu 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="10.html">Menu 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="11.html">Menu 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="12.html">Menu 12</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="direction-right pull-left navbar-brand">></span>
```

Here is your [JS.Fiddle updated with the new code](http://jsfiddle.net/k63t7tqo/12/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue is still present (note: the arrows changed from being a link to just being clickable while having the text highlighting cursor when you hover over them). Clicking either the left or right arrow simply raises or lowers the navbar location on the page. Due to the confidential nature of what I'm working on, I don't think I can link the entire page of code, otherwise that might help. Ugh..

Comment: Another thing to mention is that my navbar is not at the top of the page, but in the upper middle, already under some partial navs and a main nav bar.

Comment: Ahh ok. Yes it will be hard to help you without seeing all your code. It sounds like there are other elements on your website that may be causing issues. If you can duplicate the issue in a js.fiddle I (or someone else) could probably help you out.